# win32: check if window is minimized

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can one check whether a window is minimized using the win32 api?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

use the [IsIconic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633527(VS.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 10):

Use the IsIconic Windows API.

Answer (score 9):

Try [GetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633584%28VS.85%29.aspx) and test for the [WS_MINIMIZE style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```
LONG lStyles = GetWindowLong(GWL_STYLE);

if( lStyles & WS_MINIMIZE )
    ATLTRACE(_T("minimized"));
else
    ATLTRACE(_T("not minimized"));
```

You can also query for [GWL_EXSTYLES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Ans how is that easier than IsIconic?

Comment: I never professed to this being "easier". The OP asked how to do it using the win32 API.  Giving this answer demonstrates to the OP that he's checking a window style, which may help him in the future...

Comment: interesting. the winapi docs label `WS_MINIMIZE` as "The window is initially minimized. Same as the WS_ICONIC style.". What does "initially" mean?

Comment: WS_MINIMIZE is a style that can be applied to a window at creation time and it's meant in that context.  See CreateWindowEx for details

Comment: +1, this isn't correct. A Window doesn't lose WS_MINIMIZE when a window gets restored

Comment: I agree with that, maybe I wasn't clear.  WS_MINIMIZE is one of many styles that can be applied to a window at creation time;  but those styles stay with a window throughout its lifetime.  SetWindowLong and GetWindowLong (the focus of my answer) allow the user to read/write styles and extended styles of a window.  @Claudiu asked what "initially" meant in the context of the documentation!!!  Read the 3rd comment down!!!  If you have a look at the docs @Claudiu was referring to, you'd understand his question and my response!

Comment: @freefallr: ah in that case this isn't what I want. I want to know if a window is minimized _now_, not if it was when it was created

Comment: @Claudiu - this is what you want.  It'll give you the status of the window now.  But the same Styles are set for the CreateWindowEx() call.

Comment: I know the docs are a bit confusing, but have a look at CreateWindowEx() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680(VS.85).aspx  - it's creation requires that you specify dwStyle and dwExStyle - these are GWL_STYLE and GWL_EXSTYLE respectively.  When a windows state changes, these styles are updated to reflect the new state of the window.