# VB.NET sendkey function - cant Minimize the application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sendkeys

i know that sendkeys function is not the right way to change text of text box


i just want to try the function although that this function is **not Effective**

lets say that i got `form` with `textbox` and `timer`

```
Timer1.Interval = 1000
```

Timer1.Tick:

```
textbox1.Focus()
sendkeys.Send("123")
```

now **evrey second the timer send keys into my textbox.**

if i **Minimize** My Application the application send keys to **EvreyWhere**
lets say that i open NotePad And Then Run My Application the application send the keys into **notepad** and **not my application**

how can i send keys only to my application?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309282/win32-check-if-window-is-minimized Just test before sendkeys. Another option (might not be reliable) would be to test if textbox1 has the focus after the setfocus call.

Comment: i dont want to stop the application when i Minimize the window

Answer (score 1):

The problem is once your application is minimized it is no longer the active application. [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) sends to the **Active Application**. Take a look at this [*Forum Link*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/af8a092e-e8ec-42f5-9a72-fdfd63b31bb8) for possible options

From above link:

> Use SendKeys to send keystrokes and keystroke combinations to the
>   active application. This class cannot be instantiated. To send a
>   keystroke to a class and immediately continue with the flow of your
>   program, use Send. To wait for any processes started by the keystroke,
>   use SendWait.