# How to know if the Window is minimized via python ctypes?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes

I hide a window using codes below

```
h = windll.user32.FindWindowA(b'xxx', None)
windll.user32.ShowWindow(h, 0)
```

I need a thread to monitor if this window is reopen by other proccess, but I can't find a user32 api to do that. `windll.user32.GetWindowRect` doesn't meet my purpose either. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents). You don't need a dedicated thread for that.

Comment: If you are going to monitor manually, perhaps you are looking for [`IsIconic()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isiconic)? "*Determines whether the specified window is minimized (iconic).*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) function to start monitoring for specific events. You will need to provide a callback function to be called each time an event is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Before everything, check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions).
Even if your code works, it's still ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*!

I prepared a small example that uses [[MS.Learn]: IsIconic function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isiconic) (might also want to check [[SO]: win32: check if window is minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4309282/4788546) for more details).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import ctypes.wintypes as wts
import msvcrt
import sys


def main(*argv):
    user32 = cts.CDLL("User32.dll")
    FindWindow = user32.FindWindowW
    FindWindow.argtypes = (wts.LPCWSTR, wts.LPCWSTR)
    FindWindow.restype = wts.HWND
    IsIconic = user32.IsIconic
    IsIconic.argtypes = (wts.HWND,)
    IsIconic.restype = wts.BOOL

    title = "Untitled - Notepad"
    hwnd = FindWindow(None, title)
    print("Window ('{:s}') HWND: {:}".format(title, hwnd))
    if not hwnd:
        # Could display some error message (GetLastError())
        return
    while True:
        print("\nWindow {:s} minimized".format("is" if IsIconic(hwnd) else "is NOT"))
        print("Play with the window ((un)minimize it) then press a key (<ESC> to exit) ...")
        c = ord(msvcrt.getch())
        if c == 0x1B:
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q075227812]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Window ('Untitled - Notepad') HWND: 919796
>
> # @TODO - cfati: Window is initially unminimized
>
> Window is NOT minimized
> Play with the window ((un)minimize it) then press a key (<ESC> to exit) ...
>
> Window is NOT minimized
> Play with the window ((un)minimize it) then press a key (<ESC> to exit) ...
>
> # @TODO - cfati: Minimize window
>
> Window is minimized
> Play with the window ((un)minimize it) then press a key (<ESC> to exit) ...
>
> Window is minimized
> Play with the window ((un)minimize it) then press a key (<ESC> to exit) ...
>
> # @TODO - cfati: Restore window
>
> Window is NOT minimized
> Play with the window ((un)minimize it) then press a key (<ESC> to exit) ...
>
> Done.
> ```

As an alternative to *CTypes*, you can use [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32)), which is a *Python* wrapper over *WinAPI*s (and it's user friendlier - easier to use).